# How to remove substring in Powershell script

Tags: command-line, script, powershell

This script is almost what I need:

```
$input_path = 'C:\Common'
$output_file = 'C:\Common\extracted.txt'
$regex = 'assets'

Get-ChildItem -Path $input_path -Filter *.txt 
| Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches  
| Out-File $output_file -Force
```

The issue I have is that when I change the $inputpath to, say 'C:\Common\Data', the output file adds Data\ to the beginning of the line. Can someone tell me how to not have that last folder name in the output?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -Fo $input_path -Fi *.txt|Select-String -Patt $regex -All|%{$f=$_.path -split '\\';$f[-2]+'\;'+$_.filename+';'+$_.linenumber+';'+$_.line}|Out-File $output_file -Fo -width 400 -OutB 0x7FFFFFFF -EA 0
```

- `-OutB 0x7FFFFFFF` - file alloc buffer size - speedup create and populate file
- `-width 400` - line width at file, default size 80
- `-EA 0` = ErrorAction - skip all error
- `$f=$_.path -split '\\'` - split full file path, delimiter `\` and save parts to array `$f`
- `$f[-2]` - return 2nd element at end array $f (file directory;at this example - `Data` directory)
- `$_.filename` - file name
- `$_.linenumber` - line number, where search pattern ($regex variable)
- `$_.line` - text at line number
- `ls -Fo $input_path -Fi *.txt` <=> `Get-ChildItem -Path $input_path -Filter *.txt`
- `Select-String -Patt $regex -All` <=> `Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches`